# Inverse of a Matrix Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assuming we have a transformation T(x)=A*x what is the process for finding the inverse of the transformation T^(-1)(x)?

For example take

```
A=(1 2)
  (1 1)
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion

Comment: that is for inverting a matrix not a transformation?

Comment: I think that the biggest problem here is that OP doesnt know what a transformation is. Maybe this helps:

$$
T(x) = Ax = y
$$
So now we have $y =  Ax$, now how would I go about getting $x$ from $y$ ?

Comment: Appreciate your explanation. That was the part I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of an invertible linear transformation $T(x) = A x$ is given by $T^{-1}(y) = A^{-1} y$ where $A$ is the matrix representing the transformation (with respect to the appropriate bases - that is, if $T$ is written from basis $B_1$ to $B_2$ with matrix $A$, then $T^{-1}$ is written from basis $B_2$ to $B_1$ with matrix $A^{-1}$).